# Integrating and Caching Weather Data from Forecast.io API

Tags: plugins, json

Does anyone have any experience with integrating the forecast.io API for  location data for a Craft CMS site? I haven't been able to find any direct plugins for Forecast.io, but I was investigating the [REST plugin](https://dukt.net/craft/rest) as a possible option and I've also heard about [FeedMe](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) as well. Are there any preferred options as a best practice? My hope would be to be able to pull the data in and use it within a field of an existing entries page based on data on that entries page.

On a related note does wrapping Craft's caching tag around these plugin calls cache plugin output too? Probably a stupid question, just wanting to make sure I approach this solution correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are already several [PHP libraries](https://packagist.org/search/?q=forecast) for the [forecast.io API](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2).

I'd probably spend a few minutes reviewing those and find one that's to your liking.  Then, it's a simple as writing a [Craft plugin](http://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) that utilizes that library to make calls to their API and deal with the response as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Brad! I kind of figure that might be the way to go. Time to finally read about creating plugins for Craft.

Comment: Brad, a quick follow up question if I may. Are you aware of a plugin that uses an existing PHP package as the foundation of the plugin that I could reference in terms of development?

Comment: You can use pluginfactory.io to generate the boilerplate Craft plugin code and read over something like this to see how to integrate a composer package into a Craft plugin: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/plugin-dev-load-third-party-library/